# Is it possible to change MediaRecorder's stream?

Tags: web-audio-api, mediarecorder

```
getUserMedia(constrains).then(stream => {
    var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
})

recorder.start()
recorder.pause()
// get new stream getUserMedia(constrains_new)
// how to update recorder stream here?
recorder.resume()
```

Is it possible? I've try to create MediaStream and use **addTrack** and **removeTrack** methods to change stream tracks but no success (recorder stops when I try to resume it with updated stream)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible. The [MediaStream recording spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/) explicitly describes this behavior: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/#dom-mediarecorder-start. It's bullet point 15.3 of that algorithm which says "If at any point, a track is added to or removed from stream’s track set, the UA MUST immediately stop gathering data ...".

But in case you only want to record audio you can probably use an AudioContext to proxy your streams. Create a MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode and use the stream that it provides for recording. Then you can feed your streams with MediaStreamAudioSourceNodes and/or MediaStreamTrackAudioSourceNodes into the audio graph and mix them in any way you desire.

Last but not least there are currently plans to add the functionality you are looking for to the spec. Maybe you just have to wait a bit. Or maybe a bit longer depending on the browser you are using. :-)

https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/issues/167

https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/pull/186

Comment: chrisguttandin, i am also working on the same thing but getting issue, i also try to apply constraint to audio track but it does not show any change in audio when i see setting of audio constraint it was not change , if you have any idea how to achieve this please  let me know

Comment: I'm not sure why this is related but normally the promise returned by applyConstraints() should be rejected if it was not possible to apply the constraints. Maybe it's a good idea to file a browser bug when that doesn't happen.