# Adding an AudioTrack while the MediaRecorder is in state 'recording'

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webapi, web-mediarecorder

Im trying to add mediaTrack to the mediaStream while MediaRecorder is in state 'recording'

The code for adding a new track is the following:

```
activeStream.addTrack(newAudioTrack)
```

After that the event (onstop) was triggered. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Hi Andrew, does the answer over here solve your question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838283/is-it-possible-to-change-mediarecorders-stream/57915174#57915174

Comment: Thank you for your link, but I still have don`t understand how i can replace the track during the recording. Tracks merging with AudioContext it's OK, but before Recording, is not it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `AudioContext` to create a fixed `MediaStream` that you can pass to the `MediaRecorder`. This allows you to change the input when recording.

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode = new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode(audioContext);
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.stream);
```

Let's say you have a `MediaStream`
called `initialMediaStream`. You could connect it like that:

```
const mediaStreamAudioSourceNode = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(
    audioContext,
    { mediaStream: initialMediaStream }
);

mediaStreamAudioSourceNode.connect(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode);
```

You can then start recording the `initialMediaStream`.

```
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Later on you can replace the `initialMediaStream` with `anotherMediaStream`.

```
const anotherMediaStreamAudioSourceNode = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(
    audioContext,
    { mediaStream: anotherMediaStream }
);

anotherMediaStreamAudioSourceNode.connect(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode);
mediaStreamAudioSourceNode.disconnect();
```

You could even use `GainNode`s to apply a cross-fade between the two streams if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for you answer it is realy useful. What if my initialMediaStream also contains a videoTrack?

Comment: The MediaStream that gets exposed by the MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode only contains an audio track but you can recombine that with the video track from the initialMediaStream. Something like `new MediaRecorder(new MediaStream([ mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.stream.getAudioTracks()[0], initialMediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0] ]))` should work. The only drawback is that the video track can't be replaced while recording.